# How to deselect all selected dates at once in FSCalendar?

Tags: swift, xcode, fscalendar

I need a help for to create a function to clear all the dates selected in my FScalendar. (https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar)

I just looking into the web and found it this bucle...

```
   for (NSDate *date in _calendar.selectedDates) {
        [_calendar deselectDate:date];
    }
```

I dont understand where can i put this code into the button that i have...
Can anyone help me to understand this?
Thank you very much!
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
self.CalendarView.deselect(currentDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, i found the solution like this...

```
@IBOutlet weak var Calendario: FSCalendar!

//My Button
self.Calendario.deselect(currentDataTime)
```

The var currentDataTime change with the function didSelect!
:)